# [SOQL]: Reference Id field on a custom object without dot notation?

Tags: soql

I know that with standard objects one can do `AccountId` instead of `Account.Id` inside a SOQL query. Is it possible to do the same for custom objects, say for `My_Object__c`? Is there a way to reference the Id without using a dot `.` notation?

I am currently getting the following error if I use the dot notation: `The left operand 'My_Object__r.Id' cannot have more than one level of relationships`.

I get this when executing the following query:

```
SELECT
     Id,
     My_Object__r.Some_Field__c
FROM Opportunity
WHERE My_Object__r.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM My_Object__c WHERE Name LIKE '%myobjectname%')
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: instead of My_Object__r.Id you can just use My_Object__c

Answer (score 4):

Yes. For some custom relationship from child to parent `My_Object__r`, your Id will be `My_Object__c`, and you can reference that field in your SOQL query without performing a join/traversing the relationship. (In fact, it is preferable that you do so!)

The place you have to go somewhere special to determine the relationship name is when you're querying from parent to child, where you locate the child relationship name on the configuration of the lookup on the child.

Here, going from child to parent, your relationship name and Id field name are both derived directly from the API name of the lookup field. The Id field is just the lookup field; the relationship is the lookup field with `__r`.